# If email sent then hide the contact form div

Tags: php, html, show-hide

I have a contact form on div, I just want to hide the div after mail sent .. 
My below code is not hiding the contact form

```
<?php 
if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) 
    { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>"; 
    echo "hideDiv();" 
    echo "</script>"; 
    $msg="We have received your enquiry. We will contact you soon."; 
    } 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function hideDiv() 
{ 
document.getElementById("contact_form_div").style.display="none"; 
} 
</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<form onsubmit="return validate()"> 
<!-- contact form content--> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: which div you want to hide ? where is html of that div ? and you need to call that function hideDiv()  i dont see that you are calling function

Comment: The function is called by PHP if a mail is detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no div in your code... You need to identify the form you want to hide => add an ID

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()" id="myID">
```

Or add a div which wrap the form

```
<div id="myID">
  <form onsubmit="return validate()"> 
    <!-- contact form content--> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Then hide the form or div by selecting the ID :

```
document.getElementById("myID").style.display="none";
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if someone has javascript turned off? Why not decide what to show with if - else in php?

```
<?php
if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)) 
{
    echo "We have received your enquiry. We will contact you soon."; 
} 
else
{
?>
    <form onsubmit="return validate()"> 
        <!-- contact form content--> 
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> 
    </form> 
<?php
}
?>
```